# TFS 2008 to Build VS 2010 Projects - what version of VS should go on the TFS Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I need to get VS 2010 projects that are using Visual Studio Tests building on a TFS 2008 build server.  I didn't want to have to install VS 2010 but am now willing to do so after trying the advice one person posted here:

> http://www.richard-banks.org/2009/11/how-to-build-vs2010-solutions-using.html

and some other posts I've found but am still getting errors from the VS Test dlls.

What version of VS 2010 do I need to install to support builds with VS Tests for a TFS 2008 build server?

Comment: For test projects I am getting: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

Same error for Namespaces of: TestContext, TestMethod, TestMethodAttribute.

This only occurs on the build server, not on local machines with 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get VS 2010 projects to build using TFS 2008 source only by installing Team Foundation Server Build and Team Foundation Server 2010 Build agents.  I also had to install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008.

I followed the advice here as well to set TFS 2008 build agent to use .net 4:
http://www.richard-banks.org/2009/11/how-to-build-vs2010-solutions-using.html